# SAS proc SGPANEL controlling line or marker color based on a data value

Tags: graph, sas

I'm making a graph using proc SGPANEL in SAS.  It is animal data, so it's paneled by animal.  In each animal's graph there are 3 lines representing different blood test values.  I would like to know if I can control the color such that if the value goes out of normal limits (identified by a separate flag variable), then the data point would be red, but if the value is within normal limits the data point would be black.

I've done similar plots for just a single blood test and in that case I've presented a reference line for normal limits.  The problem with this case is that each blood test has different normal limits so I can't use that strategy.

My existing code (which doesn't incorporate the color linking with the flag variable, it just presents the data) is as follows:

```
proc sgpanel data=all;
  panelby animal / spacing=5 novarname columns=5;
  series x=dy y=value/ group=parameter markers;
  colaxis label='Day';
  rowaxis label='Value';
run;
```

Comment: One helpful hint for writing good questions: in addition to sample _code_, include sample _data_, so we don't have to go writing our own data - which might not be similar to your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to overlay your markers with new markers that only exist when the flag is set.  Here's an example.  Basically I add a new value `value_outrange` which only has a value when you want a red marker, then I ask for a scatterplot with it and red marker color.

You could also have all of the markers be overlaid in two scatterplots, one with value_outrange and one with value_inrange, which avoids two markers being in these locations; all in all it doesn't look bad though so I think just the one is fine.

```
data all;
  input animal $ dy value flag parameter;
  if flag=1 then value_outrange=value;
  else call missing(value_outrange);
datalines;
bear 1 5 0 1
bear 2 6 0 1
bear 3 7 0 1
bear 4 8 0 1
bear 5 13 1 1
bear 6 10 0 1
dog 1 8 0 2
dog 2 9 0 2
dog 3 9 0 2
dog 4 11 1 3
dog 5 10 0 3
dog 6 11 0 3
;;;;
run;

proc sgpanel data=all;
  panelby animal / spacing=5 novarname columns=5;
  series x=dy y=value/ group=parameter markers;
  scatter x=dy y=value_outrange/group=parameter markerattrs=(color=red);
  colaxis label='Day';
  rowaxis label='Value';
run;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Next time I'll include sample data as well.